# Understanding by-hand MLE logit estimation vs. optim

Tags: r, statistics

I am looking for insight as to why I must make a slight change in my gradient function to achieve the same results for a by-hand logit MLE calculation. They are coming to the same results, but I am not clear why the change, specified below, must be made.

Consider the following code:

## By Hand:

```
negLL<- function(b,X,y){  # b = betas
    p <- as.vector(1/(1+exp(-X %*% b)))  # "standard logistic function"; 1/1+exp(-X)
    -sum(y*log(p) + (1-y)*log(1-p))   # cost function; y-hat = (p)
    }

gradient<- function(b,X,y){
  p <- as.vector(1/(1+exp(-X %*% b)))
  apply(((y - p)*X),2,sum) # derivative of cost function: (p) = y-hat
  }

y <- sample(c(0, 1), size =500, replace=TRUE)
x1 <- rnorm(500)
x2 <- rnorm(500) 
x <- data.frame(x1, x2)
x <- data.matrix(x)
x <- cbind(1, x)

# the start
tol = 10^-6
beta = c(0,0,0) # multivariate now
maxit = 1000
iter = 0
alpha = 0.0001
eps = Inf

start = Sys.time()
while(eps > tol & iter < maxit){
  # save the previous value
  beta0 = beta

  # calculate h, the increment
  h =  alpha*gradient(beta, x, y)

  # update beta
  beta = beta + h

  # update the log likelihood 
  logL = negLL(beta, x, y)

  # calculate the euclidean distance
  eps  = sqrt(sum((beta - beta0)^2))

  # update the iteration number
  iter = iter + 1
  if(iter == maxit) warning("Iteration limit reached without convergence")

  # print out info to keep track
  if(floor(iter/20) == ceiling(iter/20)) cat(sprintf("Iter: %d logL: %.2f beta0: %.3f beta1: %.3f beta2: %.3f eps:%f\n",iter, logL,beta[1],beta[2],beta[3],eps))
}
```

## Optim

```
binreg<- function(X,y,method="BFGS"){
  #X<- cbind(1,X)
  negLL<- function(b,X,y){  # b = betas
    p<-as.vector(1/(1+exp(-X %*% b)))  # "standard logistic function"; 1/1+exp(-X)
    - sum(y*log(p) + (1-y)*log(1-p))   # cost function; y-hat = (p)
  }

  gradient<- function(b,X,y){
    p <- as.vector(1/(1+exp(-X %*% b)))
     -apply(((y - p)*X),2,sum) # derivative of cost function: (p) = y-hat

  }

  results<- optim (rep(0,ncol(X)),negLL,gr=gradient,
                   hessian=T,method=method,X=X,y=y, control=list(trace=1, REPORT=1))
  list(coefficients=results$par,var=solve(results$hessian),
       deviance=2*results$value,
       converged=results$convergence==0)

  }
mlebin.fit<-binreg(x,y)
#results
round(mlebin.fit$coefficients,2)
```

The only difference is: in the by-hand estimation, I remove the negative sign from the first derivative of the cost function.

```
apply(((y - p)*X),2,sum) # derivative of cost function: (p) = y-hat  # by hand
# changes to
-apply(((y - p)*X),2,sum)  # so optim works right
```

## Edit:

Is it because of the difference in algorithms, gradient descent vs BFGS; hill-descending vs hill-climbing?

Comment: This is the description of the ```optim``` function:
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/optim
"By default ```optim``` performs minimization, but it will maximize if ```control$fnscale``` is negative". Does this help?

Comment: I changed it from minimization to maximization via fnscale=-1. It will not work properly given so (the coefs are way off).

Comment: @JohnStud What do you mean "the coefs are way off"? In your example here, the coefficients should all be 0; there is no relationship between `y` and `x`. When I copy your `binreg()` function, add `fnscale = -1` to the `control` list, and remove the negative signs in `negLL()` and `gradient()`, I get essentially the same results as both `glm()` and your by-hand approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the coefficients by either

1. Maximizing the log likelihood, or
2. Minimizing the negative log likelihood

With your "by-hand" approach, you are maximizing the log likelihood; even though you are storing the negative log likelihood, the gradient that you are feeding the gradient descent method is the gradient of the log likelihood, and you are adding your steps, so it's maximization.

With your `optim()` approach, you are minimizing the negative log likelihood; `optim()` minimizes by default, and the objective function you give it is the negative log likelihood and the gradient you give it is the gradient of the negative log likelihood.

If you want to feed `optim()` the gradient of the log likelihood as you did in your manual approach, you need to also (1) give it the log likelihood as the objective function; and (2) add `fnscale = -1` to the `control` list.

Here are the results when I run your original code:

```r
## Data simulated as in your OP
## Here are results from binreg() as it is written in your OP:
mlebin.fit<-binreg(x,y)
initial  value 346.573590 
iter   2 value 346.470207
iter   3 value 346.469793
iter   4 value 346.469567
iter   5 value 346.468589
iter   6 value 346.468553
iter   6 value 346.468553
iter   6 value 346.468553
final  value 346.468553 
converged

round(mlebin.fit$coefficients,2)
[1] 0.01 0.04 0.00
```

And here's how we'd do it to maximize the log likelihood instead:

```r
## binreg() that maximizes the log likelihood rather than
## minimizing the negative log likelihood
binreg<- function(X,y,method="BFGS"){
    ## Use log likelihood, not negative log likelihood
    LL<- function(b,X,y){  # b = betas
        p<-as.vector(1/(1+exp(-X %*% b)))  # "standard logistic function"; 1/1+exp(-X)
        sum(y*log(p) + (1-y)*log(1-p))   # cost function; y-hat = (p)
    }

    ## Use gradient of log likelihood, not gradient of negative log likelihood
    gradient<- function(b,X,y){
        p <- as.vector(1/(1+exp(-X %*% b)))
        apply(((y - p)*X),2,sum) # derivative of cost function: (p) = y-hat

    }

    results<- optim (rep(0,ncol(X)), LL,gr=gradient,
                     hessian=T,method=method,X=X,y=y,
                     control=list(trace=1, REPORT=1, fnscale = -1))
    list(coefficients=results$par,var=solve(results$hessian),
         deviance=2*results$value,
         converged=results$convergence==0)

}
```

And here's the results of that approach:

```r
mlebin.fit<-binreg(x,y)

initial  value 346.573590 
iter   2 value 346.470207
iter   3 value 346.469793
iter   4 value 346.469567
iter   5 value 346.468589
iter   6 value 346.468553
iter   6 value 346.468553
iter   6 value 346.468553
final  value 346.468553 
converged

round(mlebin.fit$coefficients,2)
[1] 0.01 0.04 0.00
```

Finally, for completeness, the results of your manual approach when I ran it:

```r
Iter: 20 logL: 346.53 beta0: 0.003 beta1: 0.009 beta2: -0.001 eps:0.000413
Iter: 40 logL: 346.50 beta0: 0.006 beta1: 0.015 beta2: -0.001 eps:0.000313
Iter: 60 logL: 346.49 beta0: 0.008 beta1: 0.020 beta2: -0.002 eps:0.000237
Iter: 80 logL: 346.48 beta0: 0.009 beta1: 0.024 beta2: -0.002 eps:0.000180
Iter: 100 logL: 346.48 beta0: 0.011 beta1: 0.027 beta2: -0.002 eps:0.000136
Iter: 120 logL: 346.47 beta0: 0.011 beta1: 0.029 beta2: -0.002 eps:0.000103
Iter: 140 logL: 346.47 beta0: 0.012 beta1: 0.031 beta2: -0.002 eps:0.000078
Iter: 160 logL: 346.47 beta0: 0.012 beta1: 0.032 beta2: -0.002 eps:0.000060
Iter: 180 logL: 346.47 beta0: 0.013 beta1: 0.033 beta2: -0.002 eps:0.000045
Iter: 200 logL: 346.47 beta0: 0.013 beta1: 0.034 beta2: -0.002 eps:0.000035
Iter: 220 logL: 346.47 beta0: 0.013 beta1: 0.035 beta2: -0.002 eps:0.000026
Iter: 240 logL: 346.47 beta0: 0.013 beta1: 0.035 beta2: -0.002 eps:0.000020
Iter: 260 logL: 346.47 beta0: 0.013 beta1: 0.036 beta2: -0.002 eps:0.000015
Iter: 280 logL: 346.47 beta0: 0.013 beta1: 0.036 beta2: -0.002 eps:0.000012
Iter: 300 logL: 346.47 beta0: 0.013 beta1: 0.036 beta2: -0.002 eps:0.000009
Iter: 320 logL: 346.47 beta0: 0.013 beta1: 0.036 beta2: -0.002 eps:0.000007
Iter: 340 logL: 346.47 beta0: 0.013 beta1: 0.036 beta2: -0.002 eps:0.000005
Iter: 360 logL: 346.47 beta0: 0.014 beta1: 0.036 beta2: -0.002 eps:0.000004
Iter: 380 logL: 346.47 beta0: 0.014 beta1: 0.036 beta2: -0.002 eps:0.000003
Iter: 400 logL: 346.47 beta0: 0.014 beta1: 0.036 beta2: -0.002 eps:0.000002
Iter: 420 logL: 346.47 beta0: 0.014 beta1: 0.036 beta2: -0.002 eps:0.000002
Iter: 440 logL: 346.47 beta0: 0.014 beta1: 0.037 beta2: -0.002 eps:0.000001
Iter: 460 logL: 346.47 beta0: 0.014 beta1: 0.037 beta2: -0.002 eps:0.000001
```

So, they are all essentially the same, as we'd expect.